# Fast and Pythonic way to turn nested list into pd Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, nested

I have a list of which each element is a list with strings from a book

```
test_list = [['I love Stackoverflow', 'For ever', 'and always'], ['I dont like rain', 'it is wet']]
book_names = ['message to SO', 'confessions']
```

I would like to obtain the following dataframe

```
          book              sentence
0  message to SO  I love Stackoverflow
1  message to SO              For ever
2  message to SO            and always
3    confessions      I dont like rain
4    confessions             it is wet
```

Now, I managed to do this with the following piece of code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(test_list, index=book_names).stack().reset_index(level=0)
df.rename(columns={'level_0':'book',
                    0 : 'sentence'},
                    inplace = True)
```

Resulting in :

```
            book              sentence
0  message to SO  I love Stackoverflow
1  message to SO              For ever
2  message to SO            and always
0    confessions      I dont like rain
1    confessions             it is wet
```

Now i have to reindex the result:

```
df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

I am not particularly happy with this code, having to reset_index and renaming columns. Anyone has a better solution?

In reality the test_list is rather large so speed is also an important consideration

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think here is best create list of tuples in list comprehension with `zip` and pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([(b,s) for b, n in zip(book_names, test_list) for s in n], 
                   columns=['book','sentence'])
print (df)
            book              sentence
0  message to SO  I love Stackoverflow
1  message to SO              For ever
2  message to SO            and always
3    confessions      I dont like rain
4    confessions             it is wet
```

Only pandas solution is with [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'book':book_names ,
                   'sentence':test_list}).explode('sentence').reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
            book              sentence
0  message to SO  I love Stackoverflow
1  message to SO              For ever
2  message to SO            and always
3    confessions      I dont like rain
4    confessions             it is wet
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, amazing answer! One more question, why would you prefer the tuple/listcomprehension approach over the pandas solution? -- EDIT: nm, I prefer it myself as well, much cleaner. Thanks

Comment: @Rens - Hmm, I think it depends of data, but I think `list comprehension` should be faster here. Th best test performance in real data